# What does "buglike sunglasses" refer to?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading "Hatching Twitter: A True Story of Money, Power, Friendship, and Betrayal" by "Nick Bilton"

There is a line that describes one of characters sunglasses as "buglike sunglasses". What kind of sunglasses does this line refer to?

> “Probably me,” Noah said sarcastically, then flipped the camera around
> to document his own face, his broad smile filling the frame, buglike
> sunglasses wrapped around his eyes. “Probably me, probably me,” he
> said,  laughing slightly.

Comment: bug-like, not buglike

Answer (score 3):

The "wrapped around" phrase gives a good clue.

Wrapped around sunglasses.

[image]

http://www.photographyblogger.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/bug-eyes5.jpg

Wrapped around bug eyes

[image]

Comment: And in terms of the word's syntax, see the definition of the [adjective-combining-form sense of *like*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like#h9).